# Vaadin 24.1.10 multiple clients not detaching from broadcaster causing memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, vaadin, broadcast

we are using Vaadin 24.1.10 and updating some views using the Broadcaster. From time to time the whole application crashes due to low memory. It then turns out that our software suddenly takes up to 4 GB instead of 200MB of memory and also does not release it.
I have found out that if I have multiple tabs open in the browser, all of which have registered with our broadcast view and I then simply close the entire browser, only some clients are actually get detached from the broadcaster. Others remain and the broadcaster continues to send data to clients that do not exist. It appears that the data now stored into a buffer in memory and this continues until it is full and the software crashes.
I have tried many things but nothing works.
Can you help me please?

Broadcaster:

```
    public static final WeakHashMap<EventBusListener, Object> dashboardListeners = new WeakHashMap<>();


    public static void post(Object event) {
        synchronized (dashboardListeners) {
            dashboardListeners.forEach((listener, o) -> {
                listener.eventFired(event);
            });
        }
    }

    public static void registerEventBusListener(EventBusListener listener) {
        synchronized (dashboardListeners) {
            dashboardListeners.put(listener, null);
        }
    }

    public static void unregisterEventBusListener(EventBusListener listener) {
        synchronized (dashboardListeners) {
            dashboardListeners.remove(listener);
        }
    }
```

EventBus:

```
public interface EventBus {

public interface EventBusListener {
    public void eventFired(Object event);
}

public static void post(Object event) {
}

public static void registerEventBusListener(EventBusListener listener) {
}

public static void unregisterEventBusListener(EventBusListener listener) {
}
```

}

View:

```
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        Broadcaster.registerEventBusListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetach(DetachEvent detachEvent) {
        Broadcaster.unregisterEventBusListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void eventFired(Object event) {
        accessUiAndRun(this, this::refreshStateAndFill);
    }


    public static void accessUiAndRun(Component component, Runnable runnable) {
            component.getUI().ifPresent(ui -> {
                if (ui.isAttached()) {
                    ui.access(runnable::run);
                }
            });
    }
```

I set the heartbeat to 10 seconds, hoping that the server would quickly detect that the client n longer exists. But I think that if the broadcaster continues to push data, then the heartbeat is not necessary at all. I have additionally queries to the ui.access whether ui.isattached and Ui.ifPresent, hoping that the server will detect that the client no longer exists.
I hope there is a way to determine with certainty if there is still a client connected. It would also be good if there was a way for the broadcaster to not buffer the data in memory if no client accepts it.

thank you very much.

Comment: Could you change your LinkedList to WeakHashMap as shown in this example and observe if it helps? https://github.com/TatuLund/cdi-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/cdidemo/eventbus/EventBusImpl.java Also the latest Vaadin 24.1 version has Beacon listener built in and it will close UI immediately when browser is closed. So you do not need short heart beat for that. 10 seconds is absolutely too short as it will produce excess traffic and probably fail with hibernating browser tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have tried the weakhashmap and updated my source code above accordingly. But unfortunately that didn't help either. If I open 10 tabs of the same GUI and then close the browser, 1-5 listeners remain active and memory fills up fairly quickly. I also tried with different keys for the hashmap, but again I could not get any change.

Comment: It is important to use the listener as a key. WeakHashMap means by definition that the key is a weak reference, not the value.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, but it behaved the same way. For some reason the onDetach method is not called for all listeners and the client seems to live on. Could this also have something to do with the thread being blocked at the time and the onDetach being skipped?

Comment: I would not store the Runnable to the broadcaster. I would only store simple listener that triggers the view to run runnable that is defined in the view itself. See my repo for examples. I tend to believe that there is something in your Runnable that is preventing it to be GC'd. And yes thread being blocked could be an issue.

Comment: I have now completely rebuilt this once and used an EventBus as a key as in your repo. Unfortunately, this also does not change the behavior.
If I register a UI, then switch the page offline in the browser and then close the tab, Vaadin does not notice this and the listener remains active. If I lose the browser and reopen it, I get a new session. The old session with the UI remains active. 
Could it be that the client instantiated by Vaadin on our server continues to accept the data, but cannot forward it to the actual local client, that this memory leak then occurs?

Comment: Why you store session in the map? Note, the value is not weak reference.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't edited my code yet. But now it is modified as I had rebuilt it, which however leads to the same result.